# Any tool to do ioctl() from bash?

Tags: debian, software-rec, ioctl

I try to make an `ioctl()` call from bash. This is very easy to do in C, so there are tools ( https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/ioctl ) which wrap this functionality.

But it would make the distribution of my script a lot harder, because I would have to distribute that tool along with it.

Is there any other tool that is already included in the Debian APT repositories that can do the same? So that I could just do a simple `apt install` from the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ioctl` system call takes a parameter list that varies a lot depending on the request. Many requests take structured data as input or produce structured data as output. This makes it awkward to use from the shell. There are of course commands that wrap around a specific ioctl request or a specific set — for example `stty` with terminal ioctl — but not generic ones. The tool you link to allows passing binary data in and out, but that data is awkward to manipulate from the shell.

I recommend writing your program in a more advanced scripting language such as Perl or Python. This makes deployment easier since people won't need an obscure tool: most Unix-like systems have Perl and nowadays most have Python as well.

Perl has a predefined [`ioctl` function](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#ioctl-FILEHANDLE%2CFUNCTION%2CSCALAR) and provides access to at least some symbolic names for request values via `sys/ioctl.ph`. I don't know how you're supposed to list the available symbolic names. The extra input/output is available as a scalar (i.e. byte string).

Python has an [`ioctl` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl) in the `fnctl` module. The [`termios`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html#module-termios) module defines some symbolic names for terminal-related ioctl. The extra input/output can be passed as an integer or a byte string.

In Python, an alternative approach could be the [`ctypes` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), which is a very nice way to call C functions from a high-level language. It's nice if the ioctl you want to call is defined as taking a struct as input or output, because ctypes lets you access structs the way a C compiler would lay them out, without needing to worry about data type sizes, padding, endianness, etc.

Comment: The only call I need to execute is `ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI;
ioctl(_fd,TUNSETIFF,(void *)&ifr)` I see if I can rewrite the whole script to Python or Perl, but it will be a lot of work just for that single line.

Comment: @Maestro You can just rewrite the part that calls ioctl in a couple of lines of perl or python. Just for this one ioctl, it's something like `perl -e '$buf = pack("I", 0x1002); ioctl 0, 0x400454ca, $buf' <$fd` and the numerical values are part of the Linux kernel ABI so they should remain stable and portability to other kernels is not achievable anyway.